# Can I use a class method to set attributes of the class in Python?

Tags: python, class-method

I have a class with certain attributes.

I would like to define a method which sets other attributes based on the ones that have already been set. Something like this:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.list = []
        max = None

    def get_max(self)
        self.max = max(list)
```

This doesn't work. I have a feeling I am doing something very wrong but I can't work out what. Please someone put me out of my misery.

Updated code gives me an Attribute error:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.lst = []
        self.mx = None

    def get_max(self)
        self.mx = max(self.lst)
```

When I call the method, no exceptions are returned, but the self.mx attribute are not updated.

```
>>>t = Test('testname')
>>>t.lst = [1,2,3]
>>>t.get_max
>>>t.name
'testname'
>>>t.lst
[1,2,3]
>>>t.mx
AttributeError: Test instance has no attribute 'mx'
```

Comment: and `max` will produce the error even with `self.list`

Comment: When you say "This doesn't work" what do you mean? If you're getting an exception, please include the full traceback in your question.

Comment: Apologies for sloppily written code in original question. Hopefully the edited question clears up a bit what I want to do

Comment: Luke: this might be a typo or an edit artifact, but to call t.get_max,you need to do t.get_max() (unlike in e.g. ruby)

Answer (score 3):

It would be `self.list` to refer to the attribute, `list` is referring to the python builtin list.

You would need to do something like:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, name,lst):
        self.name = name
        self.lst = lst
        self.mx = None # use self to create an attribute

    def get_max(self):
        self.mx = max(self.lst)
```

You can also simply just call max on the list whenever you want to get the `max`, you don't need to create an attribute and  method simply to return or get the max of the list.

You should simply return the max of the list in the method if you really wanted to use a method to get the max:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, name, lst):
        self.name = name
        self.lst = lst

    def get_max(self):
        return max(self.lst)

t = Test("foo", [1,2,3,4])
print(t.get_max())

4
```

The design of your class really depends on what exactly you want to do in it but you don't getters or setters in python.

If you want to do something based on the max element in the list you don't need an attribute:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, name,lst):
        self.name = name
        self.lst = lst 

    def some_meth(self):
        if max(self.lst) > 2:
            # do something
```

Comment: uhm, max isn't shadowed :) if max was a param oder declared locally, then yes, it would shadow max :) I may be wrong, though, too lazy to start my IDE ;)

Comment: @Odi, yes but if they used it anywhere in the init method then it would be a problem. Either way  shadowing builtin names is never a good idea

Comment: Apologies for sloppily written code in question. I have made an edit which hopefully clears it up a bit. I want to use a method to update attributes of the instance

Comment: @LukeCaldwell.are you sure the code you are using is exactly as posted? The edited code works fine for me.  Also you should not completely change the code in your question as it changes what a correct answer should be, you can edit and add extra code but don't completely change it.

Comment: You must not be using the code you posted in your edit, besides a syntax error forgetting a `:` in the method the code would not throw an error because you do have an attribute mx